# React JS Label Enable display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS and I would like to perform this:

There is a button, and after I click this button, a label will display
Is there anyway to set label such as display="true" or enabled="true" something like that?

then I will be able to perform `<Label display={this.state.status}>Display After Click</Label>`
then on my `Onlick`

```
Onclick = () => {
 if (true condition){
 this.setState({status: true});
} else{
 this.setState({status: false});
}
```

let me know if there is a better solution :D

---

### Update

```
<Label display="false" //this.state.status
    className="text-danger">Display after click</Label>
<Button  onClick={this.click} color="success" block>Login</Button>


    click= () => {
     if (true condition){
     this.setState({status: true});
    } else{
     this.setState({status: false});
    }
```

so I want the `<Label>` display after the user click the button

Comment: Can you please add the whole component code? It's easier to help I guess in that way.

Comment: Hi @norbitrial I already update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that state to be true after click.

The shortest you can do is:

```
Onclick = {() => this.setState({status: true})}
```

And for the your label, you can do this instead:

```
{(this.state.status)?<Label>Some Text</Label>:""}
```

Shows Label if true and Show "" if false

Comment: so after set the status to true, how can it apply to my `<Label>` display?

Comment: your label will automatically detect it by using code below, since every changes in state will make a re render,
"this.state.status"

Comment: hmm, wait it seems like `<Label display={this.state.Status}/>` doesn't work, however the `Status` in my state change successfully

Comment: use "this.state.status" instead of "this.state.Status"
and test if Label shows if you try to manually make "display={true}" .

Comment: I try `display={false}` the `<Label>` is still there (as my case the `<Label>` is displaying), or actually the syntax of `display={false}` is actually wrong or possibly not existed?

Comment: should I use { } bracket or " " ?

Comment: update "<Label display={this.state.Status}/>" into {(this.state.status)<Label />:""}. this will work

Comment: {(this.state.status)?<Label />:""} here, i forgot the "?"

Comment: `{(this.state.status)?<Label/>:"Display After Click"};`
I try to perform above code, but the `<Label>` still exist, however, the `status` already set to false

Comment: I have updated the, answer, try out the Label i have added.

Comment: Your updated answer worked! But may I know what is the `:" "` for after `</Label>`?

Comment: You cam mark this as check if this worked, please see again the answer i added some explanations

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick sample of my take for this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      condition: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.condition && <span>{this.state.condition.toString()}</span>}
        <div onClick={() => this.setState({condition: !this.state.condition})}>Button</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply use conditional rendering like this

```
{this.state.status && <Label>Button</Label>}
```

and toggle the state like

```
 onClick = ()=>{
  this.setState(prevState=>({status: !prevState.status})
 }
```

This will mount and unmount the `<Label>` component based on the state `status`.

Hope this helps !

Comment: oh great, the condition rendering is nice! Let me take your code as my references